# How to combine multiple Google CSE by single select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search, custom-search-provider

I need to combine 2 (or more) different Google custom search engine by the means of select drop down menu. Is it possible? Didn't get any clue yet.

There should be a single search box and an adjacent drop down menu (select). Now when the search button is pressed , only one CSE should display the search-result based on which option is chosen from the drop-down menu. ( The whole thing is to be done on a single page ).

Please help guys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create two CSE that is depended on your different topic ex. food and wine. And in your webpage use either JavaScript or jQuery to switch to the respective CSE using the the chosen topic ex. on select menu choose Food which will automatically switch to the food cse ..